# Jenkins pipeline fails to run a remote script on a Jenkins node

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am trying to run the following cleanup script but it keeps failing on specific Jenkins nodes:

```
def BUILDERS = [:].asSynchronized()
def NODE_NAMES = [
    'cleanuptooldean', //test
    ]

node('master') {
    stage('Prepare the Pipeline') {
        // get deploy pattern from params 
        for (NODE_NAME in NODE_NAMES) {
            // Groovy closures stuff, need to copy it over
            def FINAL_NODE_NAME = NODE_NAME
            BUILDERS[FINAL_NODE_NAME] = {
                node(FINAL_NODE_NAME) {
                    timeout(time:5, unit: "MINUTES") {
                        echo "Started Cleaning process of unused docker images from Jenkins Instance, Agent: "+env.NODE_NAME
                        sh "docker system prune -a --volumes -f"
                        echo "Cleaning up space from unused packages (orphaned dependencies), remove old kernels in Ubuntu, Agent: "+env.NODE_NAME
                        sh "sudo apt-get -y autoremove --purge"
                        echo "clean the apt cache on Ubuntu "+ env.NODE_NAME 
                        sh "sudo apt-get -y clean"
                        echo "Finished Cleaning process of unused docker images from Jenkins Instance, Agent: "+env.NODE_NAME
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the errors I get if I type "Sudo" at the beginning of **"apt-get -y autoremove --purge"** and **"apt-get -y clean"** is: **"sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"** needless to say that I have edited the sudoers file and added **"jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"** in order to test it at the end of the file.
If I remove the "Sudo" command the error I get is: **"dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"** which I tried to resolve by adding the "Jenkins" user to the "docker" group.

** I must say that when I run the commands locally, with and without "Sudo" they both works from "Jenkins" user, but when I try to do it remotely from Jenkins using pipeline it fails.

***this specific script works perfectly on other nodes

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently each node used a different user, so I had to add all the users to the docker's group and add them to the visudo file.